# google chrome extension: code execution is not going inside of jquery for loop in .js file but for loop code works in chrome console

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, web, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my first Google Chrome extension and I have code in my JS file that looks something like this:

```
$(function() {
    console.log("hello");
    $(".panel").css("background-color", "blue");
    $(".panel .list-group .list-group-item").each(function(index, element) {
        console.log("in");
        const redoButton = document.createElement("button");
        redoButton.textContent = "Click here";
        $(element).append(redoButton);
    });
});
```

However, when I load my extension and look at the console log, only `hello` appears and the background color changes to blue.

`in` **doesn't** appear and the buttons are not added, meaning that only the inside of the for loop is not reached.

There are no errors in the console and no errors in the extensions page.

I paste the `for loop` code into the Chrome browser console and it works as expected, `in` gets printed to the console for each item and the button is added to each item.

Why is the code working in the console but not in my JS file? The code before the for loop works so I'm curious on why it isn't going inside the for loop at all.

Edit: SOLVED

@collab-with-tushar-raj's comment led me to realize that different DOM elements loaded at different speeds. The `.panel` element loaded quickly so the code at line 3 executed as expected but then the `.list-group .list-group-item` elements took longer to load so the for loop part of the script executed before those elements loaded.

I added the following `window.addEventListener('load', function() { //your script here }` code to ensure that the for loop only executes when the entire page is finished loading

Comment: As you have not provided enough information, my wild guess would be the ordering in which you are executing the script. Maybe, the script is getting executed before the DOM content is loaded which is why you see the messages in the console window but not when you are actually executing them through the JS file.

Comment: perhaps `.panel .list-group .list-group-item` doesn't match any elements ... is there `.panel` with a descendant `.list-group` with a descendant `.list-group-item`?